# builing Pardiso 5 on Mac with Julia

Tags: julia, pardiso

I'm trying to build Pardiso 5 on Mac 10.12.6 through Julia but am having issues.

I added the `Pardiso` package through Julia, then I followed the Pardiso [manual](http://pardiso-project.org/manual/manual.pdf) (p.33/69) and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.julia/v0.6/Pardiso/deps/libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib` from my `.bash_profile`. Then I run `Pkg.build("Pardiso")` and get the following error

```
INFO: Building Pardiso
found library but it failed to load due to:
could not load library "~/.julia/v0.6/Pardiso/deps/libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib"
dlopen(~/.julia/v0.6/Pardiso/deps/libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: ~/.julia/v0.6/Pardiso/deps/libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib
  Reason: image not foundfound library but it failed to load due to:
could not load library "libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib"
dlopen(libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: ~/.julia/v0.6/Pardiso/deps/libpardiso500-MACOS-X86-64.dylib
  Reason: image not founddid not find libpardiso, assuming PARDISO 5.0 is not installed
did not find MKLROOT key, assuming MKL is not installed
WARNING: no Pardiso library managed to load
```

The Julia [documentation](https://github.com/JuliaSparse/Pardiso.jl) didn't seem to indicate that I had to do any `gcc` stuff from terminal myself, so I haven't done any manual linking against BLAS/LAPACK, etc.

Any advice? Thanks!